# JavaFX: customComponent.setOnKeyPressed does not register some key inputs

Tags: java, javafx

So this is really strange and I don't know the reason for it.
I have built a custom component and I'm using the setOnKeyPressed event handler to add some functions to the component when specific key input are done. When I press the keys HOME, END, PAGE_UP or PAGE_DOWN, I don't get an output. But when I press CONTROL, ALT or SHIFT with one of those keys, I get the key code as an output. When I add the same event handler to a default pane/component, the input (only pressing one of the keys above) will be printed in the console. Does anyone know the reason for that?

```
CustomComponent customComponent = new CustomComponent();
customComponent.setOnKeyPressed((e) -> {
    System.out.println("keyInput: " + e.getCode());
    switch (e.getCode()) {
        case HOME:
            firstPage();
            break;
        case END:
            lastPage();
            break;
        case PAGE_UP:
            previousPage();
            break;
        case PAGE_DOWN:
            nextPage();
            break;
        case PLUS:
        case ADD:
        case CLOSE_BRACKET:
            zoomIn();
            break;
        case MINUS:
        case SUBTRACT:
        case SLASH:
            zoomOut();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomComponent extends Control {
    public CustomComponent() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

EDIT: i forgot to mention that the focus of the custom component is gone, when I combine one of the keys with CONTROL, ALT or SHIFT.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: sorry... I could fix the event handler by swapping setOnKeyPressed with setOnKeyReleased. Now I don't know why one of those works and the other one doesn't, but It works now.